# WSO2 REST request box not working

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I get the following error when I send a REST request with a request_box payload to WSO2 using WSO2 Tryit tool:

```
<axis2ns539:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns539="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"> 
<axis2ns539:ds_code>UNKNOWN_ERROR</axis2ns539:ds_code>
```

This is what is echoed on the console:

[2017-12-08 20:01:22,939] [] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /services/TestICM.HTTPEndpoint/request_box
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: **DS Fault Message: Input Message and request_box Axis Operation didn't match**.

I tried also with Postman and got the same error.

Thank you very much

Comment: how is your dss operation or resource defined. Share the same and also the request body / payload